# Prevent going back to previous screen with React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I'm working on an app with React Native and React Navigation. For most of the app, I have a bottom tab navigator and header. However, in one section of the app, the user can make a call and is taken to a screen with no navigation. The user shouldn't be able to navigate to the previous screen without ending the call. How can I prevent the user from going back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use react-native-navigation v5, it supports several listeners and the one you need is `beforeRemove` this is being called before the screen gets removed and you can prevent it's default behaviour conditionally.

```
   useEffect(() => {
    navigation.addListener("beforeRemove", (e) => {
       if(yourCondition) {
         return ;
        } else {
      e.preventDefault();
     }
    });
}, [navigation]);
```

Comment: for IOS its not working. and through error.